# TFS 2010 Builds Timing Out

Tags: build, tfs

I'm dealing with the following TFS 2010 build issue for the last 2 weeks and at this point completely out of options to try.

Here's the issue description:
    - builds fail with an 'operation timeout' error at various stages of the build
    - most of the time its during the GET operation (different files) 
    - other times it happens during the actual BUILD

The build definition is correct since we've had builds run properly before, the problem happened only after we moved the TFS VM onto a new WIN2012 Hyper-v server - no other changes were done to TFS or its VM.

I've checked all the paths and account permissions and everything seems to check out - really need some input on this one.

Comment: Does the build definition only download the folders it needs to complete the build? or is its workspace set to download the entire team project (or worse multiple team projects).  How long is the build running for before it times out? have you considered increasing the amount of time it's allowed?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Each build definition includes the solutions it needs, and in the build agent directory I can see appropriate folders being created when the GET operation runs. The timeout seems random, anywhere from 5 to 80+ min. Normally our build takes 20 min to complete. I have not changed the timeout, from my research it involved a registry edit, knowing that our builds take 20 min I didnt feel it was necessary.

Comment: Does running the build in verbose mode give any more detail?

Comment: We tried that yesterday, we see more trace info but nothing really useful

Comment: Did you migrate both the TFS VM and the Build Server VM to the 2012 host?

Comment: TFS and the Build Server in our case is on the same VM, which remained unchanged. Hyper-v host was the only change in the environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:

After weeks of troubleshooting we finally threw our hand up and decided to do the unthinkable - call MS Support :)

Turns out the culprit was ESET Antivirus. It was installed but disabled on the TFS VM, when we restarted the VM that must have started it back up.

According to MS Support this is a common issue, the recommended approach is to keep the VM running clean and w/o an antivirus.

Answer (score 0):

I also face same issue, After hours of research main culprit was build agent